# Angular 1.3.6 "Controller As" Not Working

Tags: angularjs, controller, angular-ui-router

I've been working on an Angular JS project that was using version 1.2.7 and recently upgraded to 1.3.6. Everything has been working great, except the "controller as" controller aliasing for views. The existing properties on the controller instance are no longer accessible in the view; in fact my alias (say "ctrl") doesn't show up in Batarang either.

The documentation for "controller as" in Angular 1.3.6 appears to be the same as it was in 1.2; did something break? Did I break something? Do I need to change something else?

I'm using UI Router, which worked before with the "controller as" mapping, but it doesn't work in the state mapping, nor in the view itself if I specify ng-controller.

Am I missing something? How can I debug and/or fix this?

Thanks!

JavaScript:

```
controller('MyController', function () {
    this.foo = 'bar';
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as myctrl">
    Foo {{myctrl.foo}}
</div>
```

myctrl is undefined

Comment: Some code example demonstrating what you are seeing would be helpful.

Comment: Try loading the page with batarang disabled. I had to turn batarang off to get things working in my own app.